# complex SQL query, many to many

Tags: mysql, sql

Complex for me as I am newbie in SQL.

I have three tables - `Peoples`, `Interests` and `Peoples_Interests` (many-to-many) - that are connected in the following way:

`People` has many `Interests` through    `Peoples_Interests`
`Interest` has many `Peoples` through    `Peoples_Interests`

I need to propose suggestions to Peoples with most similar to them Peoples, which is based on amount of similar Interests. So for **example**:

I am interested in baseball, football and volley. I should get suggestion with another user that have as many similar interests as possible. People with 3/3 occurrences should be what I need if they exist (if not - 2/3 and such).

So I need a query that output will consist of sorted by interests similarity Peoples.

**UPDATE:**
Db structure:

Interests
id
name - string

Peoples
id
email

Peoples_Interests
interests_id
peoples_id

Thank you.

Comment: It would be easer if you posted the table design in detail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this.

```
Select people.id, people.name, count(interest.id)
from people
left join people_interests on people.id = people_interests.peopleid 
left join interests on people_interests.interestid = interests.interest.id
where interests.id in (select id from interests where interests.peopleid = @inputuserid)
group by people.id, people.name
order by count(interest.id)
```

In english (which may or may not make it clearer.)

- Select the person's name and the number of interests they share
- From the people table
- Join the interests table such that that table
- Is only the interests of the person we are trying to match.
- (group by people
- and order by the number of interests that match.)

---

Updated without the sub query but less clear

```
Select people.id, people.name, count(interest.id)
from people
left join people_interests on people.id = people_interests.peopleid 
left join interests on people_interests.interestid = interests.interest.id
inner join interest i2 on (interests.id = i2.id and i2.people_id = @inputuserid)
group by people.id, people.name
order by count(interest.id)
```

Comment: that select in is going to run very very slowly in MySQL. I'd replace it with an `inner join interest i2 on (interests.id = i2.id and i2.people_id = @inputuserid)`

Comment: @johan yeah it should be updated to not use a subquery, but I was trying to make it clear to him.

Comment: I see the understandability PoV so +1.

Comment: By the way, your left joins effectively become inner joins after you use an `interests` attribute in the WHERE clause (in the first version) or in the subsequent INNER JOIN (in the second version).