# activerecord complex joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a many to many relationship and I want to get all the users of all the cars of one user. What is the most efficient join for that?

Basically, I want to know how to do the following but with activerecord
[complex SQL query, many to many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242922/complex-sql-query-many-to-many)

Comment: Can you post your schema for this join? It would be highly beneficial. However given your description wouldn't `User.where(id: User.joins(:cars).select('users_cars.user_id').where(id: some_user_id))` work for you?

Answer (score 2):

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def people_who_use_my_car
    self.cars.users
  end
end
```

In your controller or view or wherever you want to use it do:

```
@user = User.first
@users = @user.people_who_use_my_car
```

Comment: I think this needs a way to flatten the results or a joins, like `User.joins(:cars).where(cars: {user: self})`

Answer (score 0):

A straightforward way would be

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def people_who_use_my_car
    self.cars.inject([]).do |users, car|
      users += car.users
      users
    end
  end
end
```

But this is not as efficient as using the database as @poet suggests,

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  def people_who_use_my_car
    User.joins(:cars).where(cars: {user: self})
  end
end
```